# Dropdown menu failed to Load Data from Posttgres

Tags: php, postgresql, drop-down-menu

At this time the dropdown menu unable to call data from database Postgres.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php 
        <label>Payee</label>
        <form action="pg-t-payment-update.php" method="post"> 
        <select class="form-control select2"  style="width: 100%;"> 
        <?php 

        $db = pg_connect("host=10.0.32.x port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=123");
        $sql ="select distinct tenant_name FROM payment_ref_tenancy order by tenant_name asc";
        $result = pg_query($db, $sql);
        $rows = pg_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['tenant_name']).'"></option>'; 
             }  
     pg_close($db);
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['tenant_name']).'"></option>';
```

change it to:

```
echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['tenant_name']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['tenant_name']).'</option>';
```

The correct syntax of `option` is:

```
<option value="1">One</option>
```

here `value` is the text we get when use it in code, where `One` is the text which is shown to user.